# How can I find barman's configuration file /etc/barman.conf?

Tags: 16.04, server, software-installation

I have installed Barman, but I am unable to find the configuration file `/etc/barman.conf`.

When I try to open the file I have this message: `bash: /etc/barman.conf: Permission denied`

Comment: Do you mean there is no such file (after installing `barman`) or that you don't know how to find it?

Comment: When i try to open the file i have this message : "bash: /etc/barman.conf: Permission denied"

Comment: Perfectly normal. Your user has permission in you 'userspace' only. The file you want to open is owned by `root`. You can open it with `sudo -H gedit /etc/barman.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user has permissions in your ‘userspace’ only.

The file you want to open is owned by root.

You can open it with `sudo -H gedit /etc/barman.conf` where `sudo` gives you temporary elevated permissions (as `root`), the `-H` (HOME) option requests that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the target user (`root` by default) and `gedit` is the default text editor in any Gnome based distro.